# VB.net Extract Result From Google Search

Tags: vb.net, google-api, google-search, google-search-api

I want to extract google search result,
I'm using the `Google.API.Search`,

I tried to extract result by this code:

```
Dim client As New GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.co.il")
Dim results As IList(Of IWebResult) = client.Search("test", 64)
For Each result As IWebResult In results
            ListBox1.Items.Add(result.Url)
Next
Me.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count
```

This code works **partially**

the result is limited to **64** results.

i want to get 400 results,
there is another way to get result from google?

(I prefer not using the `Google.API.Search` , maybe get the result by "regex")
I'd love any other way.

Comment: You are aware that the second parameter (in your case 64) is the result size... If you want 400 results, you should specify 400 (because now you say to the API that you only want 64)!

Comment: Oh, btw, the API that you are using seems to be deprecated as well. See also: https://developers.google.com/web-search/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how this is working. But there is a integer next to the string "test" that equals 64. You are getting 64 results so I guess that could be it.

```
Dim client As New GwebSearchClient("http://www.google.co.il")
Dim results As IList(Of IWebResult) = client.Search("test", 400)
For Each result As IWebResult In results
            ListBox1.Items.Add(result.Url)
Next
Me.Text = ListBox1.Items.Count
```

Change the code to the above, should be fine!

Comment: How could I search twice ? because it tells me 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the google search api limits the search to 64 no matter if you set the limitation to exceed that.  At least that's what I read in their documentation..