# vb.net sendKeys to my application when application is minimized

Tags: vb.net, winforms, pinvoke, sendmessage, sendkeys

i want to send keys into my from when my form is minimized and **Not** in focus

```
SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
```

works but **only when** my form is on **focus**.

and this is very not convenient, if the user want to minimize the application then the application send the keys to **everywhere**, i want that the application send the keys **only** to my application.

So I need a function that looks like this:

```
Dim wb As New WebBrowser
wb.Navigate(urll)
WaitToWb()
'Send Keys To WebBrowser
SendKeysToBrowser(Me.Handle, wb, "{TAB}")
```

i need that the function send the keys only to my webbrowser, if my application is minimized the keys send **only** to the webbrowser control.

there is a function that can send keys only to my application when my application is minimized?

Comment: If you are in control of the app which you send key presses to, you can simply implement a real automation interface. You only ever have to resort to `SendKeys` if you are not in control of the target app. If the target is in fact in the same application as the sender then it's even easier.

Comment: yes, it's easier but i have no function that can send keys when my application is minimized

Comment: Let's get this straight. Are you really wanting to fake keyboard input into a window that is in the same application?

Comment: yes. i want to send keys into webbrowser control in my application, and when my application is minimized it's still send keys only to my application.

Comment: Why don't you just invoke methods on the `WebBrowser` control to get the job done? Why do you feel you have to fake input?

Comment: i tried to use webbrowser.document.getelementbyid but this specific site (google) blocked the access to the result div, so i'm using send keys and the webbrowser active element to get content from the div, its working but when i'm minimizing my application...

Comment: Hmm, now we are out of my comfort zone. But I'd be very surprised if you could not use the DOM to do what you need. In order to fake input you could try using `PostMessage` or `SendMessage` with `WM_KEYDOWN` and `WM_KEYUP` but I'd not be at all surprised if it failed. If I were you I'd ask a question here about the DOM based approach. This feels like an XY question to me. What you ultimately want to do is read information from a webpage. But you've asked a question about faking input. I'd recommend asking a question about your underlying goal.

Comment: I already asked : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13136067/vb-net-extract-result-from-goolgle-search google not let you get all search results. but with sendkeys(tab) and webbrowser current active element you can get the active element attribute (href) and add it into listbox, thanks about the ideas. I'll try it and I will update if it succeeded.

Comment: i tried everything, I'd love to a good example of send keys by sendmessage and postmessage